# Trying to install Bluez, says I need D-bus library?

Tags: bluetooth, glib

I'm trying to install Bluez so I can get bluetooth and AnyRemote working, but it keeps telling me I need a D-bus library and that I don't have one. When I try to install glib or even look through what I have, I see that I do in fact have D-bus, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.
I apologize if I'm missing something completely obvious, I'm still kind of new to Ubuntu. Any help would be amazing.

Comment: What do you mean by "install bluez" exactly? bluez, dbus, and glib are all part of the standard install on Ubuntu. Are you building them from source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my machine (12.04) bluez is already installed by default. If it is not for you, it is available in the repositories so installing it should be as easy as

```
sudo apt-get install bluez
```